# Lotus notes email in multiple folders

Tags: email, lotus-notes, organization

Is it possible to place an email into multiple lotus notes folders without creating a copy of the email? Essitiantly, I am looking for a way to create a shortcut to the same email in a different folder. For example, I have many emails relating to expenses. I would like to place the email in a folder I created called 'Airport Expenses', as well as in a folder I created called 'Business Travel DD/MM/YYYY', without duplicating the physical storage of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placing an email into multiple folders, in Notes, does not create a copy of the email - it simply adds a reference to the email to each folder. (Deleting the email will delete the one and only copy of the email, and remove references from all folders).

Answer (score 1):

Be default, dragging between folders moves the email.  If you hold the control key while you drag an email, you can add it to a new folder without removing it from the original folder (i.e. copy it to a folder).